# How do I left-align numbers in columns in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write a function that passes this doctest:

```
Prints a table of values for i to the power of 1,2,5 and 10 from 1 to 10
left aligned in columns of width 4, 5, 8 and 13
>>> print_function_table()
i   i*2 i*5    i*10
1   1    1       1
2   4    32      1024
3   9    243     59049
4   16   1024    1048576
5   25   3125    9765625
6   36   7776    60466176
7   49   16807   282475249
8   64   32768   1073741824
9   81   59049   3486784401
10  100  100000  10000000000
```

I feel like I am almost there but I can't seem to left-align my columns.

the code i have is:

```
def print_function_table():
    i = 1
    s = "{:^4} {:^5} {:^8} {:^13}"
    print s.format("i", "i*2", "i*5", "i*10")
    while i <= 10:
        print s.format(i, i*2, i*5, i*10)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Side note: Use `for i in range(1, 11):` instead of a while loop.

Comment: Side note 2: Why *require* left-alignment, when right-alignment is easier and more readable?

Answer (score 5):

What about...

```
def print_function_table():
    s = "{:<4} {:<5} {:<8} {:<13}"
    print s.format("i", "i*2", "i*5", "i*10")
    for i in range(1,11):
        print s.format(i, i**2, i**5, i**10)
```

?

Comment: Note: `"{} {}".format()` is valid starting with Python 3.1+; for previous versions one should use `"{0} {1}".format()` (with explicit indexes), see http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html §6.1.3.2.

Comment: @Joël Not really true, current python 2.7.3 doc [mentions this too](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings). Py3k features like to be backported

Comment: this would be prettier with eval instead of repeating the header :)

Comment: @ArnabDatta Maybe it'd look pretty, but for sure less clear as well.